# Selective Forwarding | SMS Forwarding

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, sms

Does anybody know a way to create a rule in Gmail to forward emails from a specific contact or email address?

If so, is there a way to forward to SMS?

I've tried playing around with the filtering but this needs a global forwarding address?

Comment: I guess you cant

Comment: a) You asked this in the wrong forum. b) It has been just 2 hours. Some people wait for days.

Comment: @dnbrv I'm used to SO flow where you get an answer in 15 seconds lol sorry

Comment: @iglvzx: I've flagged it for migration a few hours ago. It's strange it's taking mods so long to do it.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: Not everything on SO gets answered so quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup a filter that is `from:sender's@domain.com` that forwards to an address you've added in. Almost every phone carrier offers a free email → SMS converting with your plan.

- T-Mobile: phonenumber@tmomail.net
- Virgin Mobile: phonenumber@vmobl.com
- Cingular: phonenumber@cingularme.com
- Sprint: phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
- Verizon: phonenumber@vzwpix.com
- Nextel: phonenumber@messaging.nextel.com

Where `phonenumber` = your 10 digit phone number.

[SMS Address Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/).

Comment: this will work fine i am using it now:)

Comment: The problem I've run into with this is Gmail sends a verification email to the address in question.  In the case of Verizon, the email is too long and the verification number doesn't get through.

Comment: Found the answer.

http://bit.ly/11K1r3D

Forward to the MMS address instead.  For example, `number@vzwpix.com` == MMS on Verizon

Answer (score 1):

There are several services available online that will convert e-mails to SMS (usually for a small fee).

Gmail allows you to add a forwarding address, as long as you can verify that you own the account by clicking the link in the verification mail. Once added, you can create a filter that will forward only selected e-mails, such as only e-mails coming from a specific address.

Comment: Yeah I know how to set up basic forwarding and also to sms email from gmail ... I was wondering of there was a slick way to do it on a per contact basis ...